# Wrapping method call with PostSharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

Is there any way to wrap a method call with PostSharp? I have to add code around/outside a specific call.

The `OnMethodBound` add the code **inside** the specified method and the `MethodInterception` aspect redirects the call to the aspect, but I have to to add code outside the call.

**Example:**
Without aspect:

```
...
call();
...
```

With aspect:

```
beforePart();
call();
afterPart();
```

Comment: Why can't you use MethodInterceptionAspect.OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args) and put the before and after around the args.Proceed?

Comment: I'm calling a synchronized method and it looks like that the Aspect is synchronized too, if I'm using the MethodInterceptionAspect. But the aspect's code should not be synchronized.

Comment: If your program is synchronized you can wrap all methods with postsharp but only do want you want when a condition is valid, for example a boolean value, and set the condition true when call beforePart() method, and set to false when call afterPart() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only scenario in which PostSharp weaves the aspect around the call site is when you apply that aspect to a method in the referenced assembly.

When applying an aspect in your project, you can set the name of the external assembly in the [AttributeTargetAssemblies](http://doc.postsharp.net/p_postsharp_extensibility_multicastattribute_attributetargetassemblies) property.

```
[Log(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "SomeLibrary", ...)]
```

PostSharp, of course, will not modify the existing external assembly, instead it will weave the aspect in your project's assembly around the calls to the referenced assembly.

Applying the aspect to the calls of the methods from the same assembly is not currently supported. In most scenarios this is not required, or there should be a reasonable workaround.

Maybe we'll be able to solve this if you provide more details about your synchronized method and why it's not possible to use method interception.

**Update.**

The possible workaround is to introduce the synchronization locks using aspects. You can write a custom [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator) or use [SynchronizedAttribute](http://doc.postsharp.net/synchronized) from the Threading Pattern Library.

Then you can use [Aspect Dependency or Aspect Priority](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-dependencies) to make sure that the measuring aspect is introduced before the threading aspect. This way the behavior will be the same as when introducing the measuring aspect around the call site.

```
[Serializable]
[AspectTypeDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Order,
                      AspectDependencyPosition.Before,
                      typeof(SynchronizedAttribute))]
public class MeasureTimeAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I want to measure the runtime (including waiting or sleep time) of certain methods. For this, I store the time of the method's enter end exit "event". Like you said, in external assemblies it works perfect but in synchronized methods in the local project, I cannot measure the time which occures by Locks or synchronization because of those locks.

Comment: Do you introduce those synchronization locks using aspects as well? Or is it just manually written synchronization code?

Comment: Those synchronization locks are manually added by the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` method attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement and I wrote a logging aspect for all database calls I make with external library which is Dapper. I created an aspect:

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method)]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class SqlLogger : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        // logging code goes here

        base.OnInvoke(args);
    }
}
```

And then I registered it on assembly level:

```
[assembly: SqlLogger(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "Dapper", AttributePriority = 1)]
```